# Symmetric eigenfunctions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, wavefunction, eigenvalue

So a symmetric eigenfunction / wavefunction is defined as:
$$P_{ij} ψ_a (r_1,r_2,…,r_i,…,r_j,…,r_N )=ψ_a(r_1,r_2,…,r_i,…,r_j,…,r_N )$$
But for it to be symmetric does this have to be true for all $ij$ combinations or only one? (note that $P_{ij}$ is the exchanges the element $r_i$ for $r_j$)

Comment: sorry I have changed it (question would still hold for anti symmetric)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's just terminology:

A (wave)function $\psi(x_1,\dots,x_N)$ is

- *symmetric* in $i,j$ iff $\psi(x_1,\dots,x_i,\dots,x_j,\dots,x_N)  = \psi(x_1,\dots,x_j,\dots,x_i,\dots,x_N)$
- *antisymmetric* in $i,j$ iff $\psi(x_1,\dots,x_i,\dots,x_j,\dots,x_N)  = -\psi(x_1,\dots,x_j,\dots,x_i,\dots,x_N)$
- *fully symmetric* iff symmetric in all $i,j$
- *fully antisymmetric* iff antisymmetric in all $i,j$.

The wavefunction of multiple bosons is fully symmetric, the wavefunction of multiple fermions is fully antisymmetric.